# Hiding or showing shiny elements without pressing submit

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app where i want to hide or show some elements based on user input. This i tried to do by using `conditionalPanel` in shiny. However, it works only after pressing the submit button. I want to hide or show the `textInput` element without pressing the submit button. Below is an example what I tried.

UI.R

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("submitButton example"),
  fluidRow(
    column(3, wellPanel(
      sliderInput("n", "N:", min = 10, max = 1000, value = 200,
                  step = 10),
      checkboxInput("checkbox", label = "Message", value = FALSE),
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.checkbox == true",
        textInput("text", "Text:", "text here")),

      submitButton("Submit")
    )),
    column(6,
           plotOutput("plot1", width = 400, height = 300),
           verbatimTextOutput("text")
    )
  )
))
```

Server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    hist(rnorm(input$n))
  })

  output$text <- renderText({
    paste("Input text is:", input$text)
  })
})
```

I want to show the `textInput` as soon as user checks the `checkbox`  and hide it on uncheck without any dependency on `submit` button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

UI:

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("submitButton example"),
  fluidRow(
    column(3, wellPanel(
      sliderInput("n", "N:", min = 10, max = 1000, value = 200,
                  step = 10),
      checkboxInput("checkbox_1", label = "Message", value = FALSE),
     uiOutput('test')

      ,actionButton("Submit",label ="Submit" )
    )),
    column(6,
           plotOutput("plot1", width = 400, height = 300),
           verbatimTextOutput("text")
    )
  )
))
```

server:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {
  output$test=renderUI({ 
    if(input$checkbox_1==T){
      list(textInput("text", "Text:", "text here"),
           numericInput("num","num",0), numericInput("num1","num1",0))}
  })

  observeEvent(input$Submit,{
    output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
      hist(rnorm(isolate(input$n)))
    })
    output$text <- renderText({
      paste("Input text is:", isolate(input$text))
    })

  })

})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Message in `textInput` should reflect only after pressing the submit button. In your answer, it does not depend on `submit ` but  appears instantly.

Comment: Not fully understand what you want. You want that hist and verbatimTextOutput("text")  changed only after submit?

Comment: Yeah, exactly, that should appear after pressing submit

Comment: Edit my answer, its what you want? ( you made text and plot reactive after first click Submit delete isolate.

Comment: i can only try)  You cant use Submit button and reactive in one app ( my mind) , but more flexible is `actionButton` + `observeEvent` + `isolate` .. it give you reactive part of app and isolated what you want( in you example its input used in `output$plot1` and `output$text`)

Comment: Thanks. Can i do it for a group of elements. For example i want to hide or show `numericInput("num")`, `numericInput("num1")`, `textInput("text")` all together.

Comment: Edit my answer .. you can create a list of elemets or create some if statemen if you want to show in different place