# Hide/show results with submit button in Shiny with shinyjs

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

I'm trying to create a Shiny app that includes a submit button for inputs and a checkbox for hiding/showing the results. My issue is that ticking or unticking the hide/show checkbox has no effect unless I hit the submit button again.

How can I show results as soon as the user checks the checkbox and hide it on uncheck without any dependency on submit button? It's similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33951152/hiding-or-showing-shiny-elements-without-pressing-submit) question, but I'm using the shinyjs package instead.

Here is some sample code to illustrate the issue:

UI.R

```
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
# Initiate shinyjs package
useShinyjs(),
                    # Select layout type 
                    sidebarLayout(
                        # Sidebar content
                        sidebarPanel(
                            # Input phrase1
                            textInput("phrase1", "Enter a word or phrase here", "It’s not rocket"),
                            # Input phrase2
                            textInput("phrase2", "Enter a word or phrase here", "science"),
                            # Submit button
                            submitButton("Paste phrases")
                        ),
                        # Main panel content
                        mainPanel(
                            # Checkbox to show/hide results
                            checkboxInput("checkbox", "Show results?", TRUE), 
                            # Results
                            textOutput("full_phrase")
                        )
                    )
))
```

Server.R

```
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
        observe(toggle("full_phrase", condition=(input$checkbox==T)))
        output$full_phrase <- renderText({paste(input$phrase1, input$phrase2)})
})
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `submitButton` control his halting all reactivity until it is clicked.  If you want any elements of your UI to be reactive independent of your button, you should use `actionButton` instead, and use an event observer for the actions that you want performed when the button is clicked.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

shinyApp(
  ui = 
    shinyUI(fluidPage(
      # Initiate shinyjs package
      useShinyjs(),
      # Select layout type 
      sidebarLayout(
        # Sidebar content
        sidebarPanel(
          # Input phrase1
          textInput("phrase1", "Enter a word or phrase here", "It's not rocket"),
          # Input phrase2
          textInput("phrase2", "Enter a word or phrase here", "science"),
          # Submit button
          actionButton("paste_phrase",
                       label = "Paste phrases")
        ),
        # Main panel content
        mainPanel(
          # Checkbox to show/hide results
          checkboxInput("checkbox", "Show results?", TRUE), 
          # Results
          textOutput("full_phrase")
        )
      )
    )),

  server = 
    shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
      observe({
        toggle("full_phrase", 
               condition=input$checkbox)
      })

      pasted_phrases <- 
        eventReactive(
          input$paste_phrase,
          {
            paste(input$phrase1, input$phrase2)
          }
        )

      output$full_phrase <- 
        renderText({pasted_phrases()})
    })
)
```